# Convert JSON string to Object or array

Tags: javascript, json

Data from previous result to be used as input and change that to a format I can make use to query my following actions.

The JSON String received is:
Example:

```
var a = apple,car,earth
var b = fruit,vehicle,planet
```

Desired final output in Array :
when apple is queried it should list fruit
when car is queried it should list vehicle
when earth is queried it should list planet

Comment: `var a = apple,car,earth var b = fruit,vehicle,planet` is not JSON format

Comment: That doesn't even remotely resemble JSON.

Comment: That's still not JSON. Are you loading a JavaScript file?

Comment: Why do you want to convert it to JSON and to an object if the final result is an array? Are you even sure you want an array?

Comment: I don't understand if your string output is `apple,car,earth` or if it is `var a = apple,car,earth` (is `var a = ` part of the string too?)

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is what you are looking for...

```js
var a = 'apple,car,earth'
var b = 'fruit,vehicle,planet'
a = a.split(',')
b = b.split(',')

d = {}

for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
    d[a[i]] = b[i];

console.log(d['apple'])
console.log(d['car'])
console.log(d['earth'])
```

Comment: Yes, this is roughly what I am looking for. I can continue from here. Thank you for the assistance.

Answer (score 0):

It should be straightforward using "Map".

```
let a = 'apple,car,earth'.split(',');
let b = 'fruit,vehicle,planet'.split(',');
const MapOfItems = new Map();
a.forEach((item, index) => MapOfItems.set(item, b[index]));
console.log(`\nobj`, MapOfItems);
```